# What to do with broken nylon tights?

Tags: reuse, clothing

I happen to break some nylon tights(pantyhose) each season, is there any alternative to just throw them in the garbage? I keep a couple of them for wearing under the jeans in exceptionally cold days, but besides that I don't have any idea. I guess they are not even recyclable

Comment: Welcome to Sustainable Living! I like your question, but you are basically asking for a (potentially endless) list of things. So there isn't one definitive good answer we can give. Therefor list-questions are often closed on all SE sites. It's best to try to refine your question or alternatively if people agree we can turn this question into a community-wiki question.

Comment: Yes, i see the issue, in fact i wouldnt know which answer to accept... actually i couldnt really imagine any use and now i am surprised to see  different suggestions!

Answer (score 8):

You can use old nylons as

- Stuffing for pillows/cushions
- Polishing or cleaning cloth (no worry that you'll make scratches, plus it's great for attracting dog and cat hair).
- Hanging storage to dry unions
- As a filter in a drainpipe (e.g. to keep any leaves out of your rain barrel)
- Protection cover for fruit (this one is not from personal experience, but I've heard from other people that it helps protect their fruit growing in the garden from bugs)

Answer (score 7):

I've used them as ties to fasten tomato bushes to trellises. They work pretty good for that. Curious to see what others come up with.

Answer (score 5):

I use old tights for jar covers while [sprouting lentils](http://www.theleangreenbean.com/how-to-sprout-lentils) - they provide enough air while not letting flies or pests in.

If you brew kombucha or water kefir you could use tights for the same purpose (for first fermentation stage or if you don't care about carbonation).

Answer (score 4):

Along the lines of m.w.jacobsen's suggestion, if you've planted a new tree, they are great for tying the tree to stakes while its roots develop. They are also great for cleaning walls in your house, because they don't leave any lint behind.